# SSRS Subscription Error : An error has occurred during report processing.Mail will not be resent

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I would really appreciate any help :) Please assist me to solve this error.

I have created a report an SSRS report in VS 2008, and running it on a Windows Server 2012. When I run the report from Report Manager, it runs with no issues. However, when I set up a scheduled subscription, I get the following error message:

> Failure sending mail: An error has occurred during report processing.
>   Mail will not be resent.

I am unable to find any more specific information on the exact error.

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic933849-150-1.aspx

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58629/ssrs-subscription-error-failure-sending-mail-report-processing-has-been-cance